# how can I capture console error messages to a file?

Tags: console

I have a process that is causing a reboot.   I'd like to capture any console messages to the messages are not lost.   How can I do that?

Comment: The kernel messages from a kernel panic should still appear in /var/log/messages after a reboot. It maybe just that the messages are in an older message file after log rotation.

Answer (score 2):

**Bash redirect:**

```
program > stdout_log 2> stderr_log
```

If you want to *append* instead of overwriting:

```
program >> stdout_log 2>>stderr_log
```